# Why is my Map broken?

Tags: java, multithreading, reference, dictionary, hashtable

**Scenario**: Creating a server which has *Room* objects which contain *User* objects.

I want to store the rooms in a *Map* of some sort by *Id* (a string).

**Desired Behavior**:

When a user makes a request via the server, I should be able to look up the Room by id from the library and then add the user to the room, if that's what the request needs.

Currently I use the static function in my Library.java class where the Map is stored to retrieve Rooms:

```
public class Library {

  private static Hashtable<String, Rooms> myRooms = new Hashtable<String, Rooms>();

  public static addRoom(String s, Room r) {  
    myRooms.put(s, r);
  }

  public static Room getRoomById(String s) {
    return myRooms.get(s);
  }
}
```

In another class I'll do the equivalent of `myRoom.addUser(user);`

What I'm observing using Hashtable, is that no matter how many times I add a user to the Room returned by getRoomById, the user is not in the room later.

I thought that in Java, the object that was returned was essentially a reference to the  data, the same object that was in the Hashtable with the same references; but, it isn't behaving like that. Is there a way to get this behavior? Maybe with a wrapper of some sort? Am I just using the wrong variant of map?

Help?

Comment: It would be good to see the code for Room as well.

Comment: It would figure that as soon as I post this I connect the dots. I'm coming back to this after 4 months of not looking at this code. I had a little snippet of code hidden in user that basically did this:


setRoomPseudo(Room r) {
if(myRoom != null)
myRoom.removeMe()
myRoom = r
}

So, I forgot it worked like that and did operations out of order. fixed, and sorry for the trouble. I do understand maps afterall, and java, just not myself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very peculiar that you declare `myRooms` as `Hashtable<String, Rooms>` (plural `Rooms`), but you `put` a singular `Room r` in `addRoom`.

Are you trying to do some sort of multimap, where a key can map to a multiple values? If so, then either us the [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r8/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) implementation, or implement your own as a `Map<K,Set<V>>` (map a key to a *set* of values).

I'm not sure if this your fundamental issue, though.

It is correct that the returned value by `get` should be the same object, as defined by reference equality, as the one used in `put`.

```
    Object someObject = new Object();
    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    map.put("key1", someObject);
    System.out.println(map.get("key1") == someObject); // prints "true"

    someObject = "something else";
    System.out.println(map.get("key1") == someObject); // prints "false"
```

The above is expected behavior.

Sometimes people have trouble with a `Map` because their key objects do not implement `hashCode` and `equals` contract properly, but if you're using `String` as keys, this should not be an issue.

By the way, `Hashtable` has a newer, sexier cousin in `HashMap`. I noticed the `multithreading` tag in the question, so if you actually need the `synchronized` feature, you can use [`Collections.synchronizedMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29)

In either case, whether you use a `HashMap` or a `Hashtable`, you want declare  `myRooms` simply as a `Map` (see *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces*).

#### Related questions

- [Overriding equals and hashCode in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)
- [Understanding the workings of equals and hashCode in a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894377/understanding-the-workings-of-equals-and-hashcode-in-a-hashmap)
- [Java hashmap vs hashtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/java-hashmap-vs-hashtable)
- [Difference between a Deprecated and Legacy API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873254/difference-between-a-deprecated-and-legacy-api)

Comment: It would figure that as soon as I post this I connect the dots. I'm coming back to this after 4 months of not looking at this code. I had a little snippet of code hidden in user that basically did this: setRoomPseudo(Room r) { if(myRoom != null) myRoom.removeMe() myRoom = r } So, I forgot it worked like that and did operations out of order. fixed, and sorry for the trouble. I do understand maps afterall, and java, just not myself!

Answer (score 0):

Does your code even compile?

```
public class Library {

  private static Hashtable<String, Rooms> myRooms = new Hashtable<String, Rooms>();

  public static addRoom(String s, Room r) { // Your hashtable holds Rooms yet you add a Room
    myRooms.put(s, r);
  }

  public static Room getRoomById(String s) { // Again, returning a Room, instead of Rooms
    return myRooms.get(s);
  }
}
```

Just by looking at this, it shouldn't compile. Now I can only assume that it was a typo, and if that's the case then show us the `Room` code where you're trying to add a user to the room.

Comment: It would compile if `Room extends/implements Rooms`. It is peculiar, though.

Comment: It would figure that as soon as I post this I connect the dots. I'm coming back to this after 4 months of not looking at this code. I had a little snippet of code hidden in user that basically did this: setRoomPseudo(Room r) { if(myRoom != null) myRoom.removeMe() myRoom = r } So, I forgot it worked like that and did operations out of order. fixed, and sorry for the trouble. I do understand maps afterall, and java, just not myself!