# Joda Equivalent of Date data structure

Tags: java, jodatime

The Date data structure from java.util is almost being depreciated. Hence, we use to have our very own data structure to represent **Date** (With year, month and date only. No time information)

[SimpleDate](http://jstock.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/jstock/jstock/annotate/ed5687b5b95c/src/org/yccheok/jstock/engine/SimpleDate.java)

**I was wondering is there any equivalent data structure in Joda library?**

If my project would like to convert to use Joda, there are some extra work. Because previously my project is using convention in Java Calendar, by having **January as 0**. In Joda, the **January is 1**

Comment: So what if `Date` get deprecated in Java 7? It's not going to suddenly stop working.

Comment: Given the massive legacy of tooling dependant on Date, it's not going anywhere soon.

Comment: @skaffman, Date is almost not usable, as getDate, getMonth, getYear are depreciated. I feel very uncomfortable to use method which is marked as depreciated.

Comment: @Yan Cheng CHEOK: Then don't use those methods. A Date is supposed to represent an instance in time. If you want to break that instance down into its components, then use Calendar.

Comment: @GaryF, What the point of having Date to present an instance of time, and you cannot get primitive date/month/year information out form it in a straight forward way? Calendar are having poor performance compared to Joda time. We are currently in the process of migrating. http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jstock/index.php?title=NextRelease#Some_offline_study_on_the_performance_of_Calendar_and_Joda_DateTime

Comment: Deprecated methods/classes in JavaSE will never be removed. It just indicates that a better option exists.

Comment: I will always avoid using depreciated method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941900/is-it-wrong-to-use-deprecated-methods-or-classes-in-java

Comment: @Yan Cheng CHEOK: You don't always need to get those things individually. In my experience, you generally need to persist dates, display them (DateFormat classes) and compare them. It's not often that I find I need anything else. BTW, I prefer Joda's LocalDate to java.util.Date, but the latter isn't going anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DateTime#toLocalDate()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#toLocalDate%28%29) to obtain the local date part.

```
LocalDate localDate = dateTime.toLocalDate();
```

Note that months are nowhere in JodaTime 0-based.

Comment: Do you mean month is joda is 0-based? but my testing on dateTime.getMonthOfYear() is that, it returns 12 for December???

Comment: I said, ["nowhere"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nowhere). It was just a warning because the last sentence in your question seem to indicate that you need 0-based months.

Comment: I am apologize for my misinterpret :)

Comment: I'm a native English speaker and I also found your usage of "nowhere" to be confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Joda uses [LocalDate](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) to represent a date without time or timezone information.