# how to write this mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a social networking feature's site which has a section like facebook PEOPLE YOU MAY KNOW that consists the person who are not friends of logged in user.

TABLE 1 'users' structure:
uid(primary),
fname,
lname, dob, etc.

TABLE 2 'friend_request' structure:
id(primary)
uid,
fid,
created

TABLE 3 'friends' structure:
same as 'friend_request'

I want to show people other than logged in user and his/her friends.Because i want to keep it simple.

MYSQL query is below:

```
     <?php 
   /*
   section for displaying random person who are not friends.
   */
   $q =mysql_query("select * from users where uid!='".$_SESSION["logged"]."'");
   if(mysql_num_rows($q)>0)
     {
        while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($q))
     {

    $sel=mysql_query("select * from friends where (uid='".$fetch["uid"]."' and
        fid!='".$_SESSION["logged"]."') or                    
     (uid!='".$_SESSION["logged"]."' and fid='".$fetch["uid"]."')") or   
          die(mysql_error());

      $num_rows=mysql_num_rows($sel);
      if($num_rows>0)
        {
        while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sel))
         {

        $que=mysql_query("select * from users where uid='".$rows['uid']."' or
          uid='".$rows['fid']."'");                    
         if(mysql_num_rows($que)>0)
           {
            while($names=mysql_fetch_array($que))


            {

              ?>
        <li><a href="user_index1.php?id=<?php echo $names['uid']; ?>"><strong>
       <?php echo $names['fname']." ".$names['lname'] ?></strong></a></li>
       <?php }
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: i think my queries are wrong. Please suggest something so that i can detect the problem.

Comment: what you exactly want to do you combined so many queries you can write it in single query

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I know PDO but i am using conventional way because it works soon for me. But this news is really bad. Thanks for this info.

Comment: @vinaysingh Your way ***is not*** conventional.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO But this is for PHP 5.5.0 and i am using PHP 5.3

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941900/is-it-wrong-to-use-deprecated-methods-or-classes-in-java for why you shouldn't use depreciated functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is :

```
   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `uid` NOT IN 
   (SELECT `uid` FROM `friends` WHERE `uid` = 1 or 'fid' = 1 union SELECT `fid` FROM 'friends' WHERE 'uid'=1 or 'fid'=1)
   AND `uid` != 1;
```

This will show the person who are not friend with uid=1 excluding logged in user. Thanks
@RachelID for his suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`
        WHERE `id` NOT IN 
            (SELECT `fid` FROM `friends` WHERE `uid` = ".$_SESSION["logged"].")
        AND `id` != ".$_SESSION["logged"].";";

$que = mysql_query($sql);
```

---

By your comments I think were miss understanding each other. I have recreated the following tables in my MySQL database like so:

**users**

```
id    fname    lname
1      Bob1     One
2      Bob2     Two
3      Bob3     Three
4      Bob4     Four
5      Bob5     Five
```

**friends**

```
id    uid     fid
1      5       2
2      5       3
3      3       1
4      2       1
5      2       4
```

Then when I run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `users`
WHERE `id` NOT IN 
    (SELECT `fid` FROM `friends` WHERE `uid` = 1)
AND `id` != 1
```

I get the following result:

```
uid    fname    lname
2      Bob2     Two
3      Bob3     Three
4      Bob4     Four
5      Bob5     Five
```

Can you explain to me why that's not what your looking for? Or that Im not entering data into the databases incorrectly?

Comment: @RachelID sorry for previous comment.It is not working correctly. friends are including in result.

Comment: I may not be understanding your database structure the way you described it. For the friends table the uid would be the logged in user and the fid would be the user.id for their friends right? Because that's what I was working with.

Comment: no. that's not the case. uid and fid is both taken from TABLE users' uid. so logged in user may also in fid. That's why these queries are so messy.

Comment: That's what I was saying. Please see my edit where I explain what I mean more thoroughly.

Comment: okay. i am checking my codes.

Comment: Great. Hope it works for you. If it does work out please accept my reply as the correct answer.

Comment: @RachelID i edited your table. Please run this and see what happens.if UID of friends TABLE doesn't contain 1, then it shows wrong result.

Comment: According to your question you want return all users, that are not the logged in user and that are not the friends of the logged in user. So if you do not have any friends for the logged in user then you will return all users except the logged in user. Why is that not what you are asking for?

Comment: See my edit for updates

Comment: I have found the solution today.Now you can check my edits above.