# Remove/Deprecate a method in subclass

Tags: java, deprecated, overriding

I want to remove a method from a class that is present in it's super class. I can deprecate the superclass method using the `@Deprecated` annotation, but it is still accessible in the subclass.

Eg:

```
public class Sample {

    void one() {}

    void two() {}

    @Deprecated
    void three() {}
}

class Sample2 extends Sample {
    @Override
    void one() {}

    public static void main() {
        Sample2 obj = new Sample2();
        obj.one();
        obj.two();
        obj.three();// I do not want to access this method through the sample 2 object.
    }
}
```

While using the `Sample2` object I only want methods `one` and `two` to be available. Please advice on how to do this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Deprecated Doesn't mean that you cant access them. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941900/is-it-wrong-to-use-deprecated-methods-or-classes-in-java @Deprecated is one that programmers are discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous, or because a better alternative exists.

Comment: @ Nikhil Ok. How to make this scenario possible ?

Comment: Is `Sample.three()` currently being called from outside `Sample`, or can you make it private? Currently it is only visible to other classes in the same package

Answer (score 2):

Override three() in Sample2 and throw an exception if that method is accessed.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do at compile-time. You cannot have a subclass with less methods than a superclass. Best you can do is make a runtime error like @Sudhanshu proposes, and maybe some tooling (like custom FindBugs rules) to flag it an error in your IDE.

Comment: If so How a method is removed in some version of Java release.

Comment: So far, no method has ever been removed in Java releases. And even if they did, that would remove the method in a new version of the class. The type hierarchy would still remain consistent, i.e. you cannot have "incomplete" subclasses (provided you don't mix releases).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `private` access level modifier in front of methods that should only be accessed in their own classes.

```
public class Sample {

    void one() {}

    void two() {}

    @Deprecated
    private void three() {}
}
```

Comment: This answer assumes you have the ability to edit the source for `Sample .java`, and that `Sample.three()` can be made private without breaking existing code.

Answer (score 0):

One idea for hiding the interface of another class while still using it is to wrap it with your own object (i.e. don't subclass).

```
class MySample {
    private Sample sample;
    //maybe other stuff

    public MySample(){ 
        sample = new Sample();
    }

    void one(){
        return sample.one();
    }
}
```

This is potentially unsatisfactory: not wanting to use `Sample` in the entire way it was intended while simultaneously wanting to hijack and extend its behavior. It solves the problem of ever calling `three()` on your backing `Sample`.