# overrides a deprecated API

Tags: java

I'm working on a Project. When I tried to build this project a problem appears :

> Note: C:\Users\Documents\NetBeansProjects\application.backoffice1\src\login.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

This is my class 'login' :

```
/*Importation des différents bibliothèques
  les bibliothèques pour établir la connexion à la DB
  les bibliothèques de gestion des requêtes SQL
*/

import java.sql.Connection;

import static java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class login extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    
  Connection con=null;
  ResultSet rs=null;
  Statement stmt=null;
  public static String nu="";
  //construction de la fenêtre login   
  public login() {
    initComponents();
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.pack();
    java.awt.Dimension screenSize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    this.setLocation(
    (screenSize.width-this.getWidth())/2,
    (screenSize.height-this.getHeight())/2);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
  private void initComponents() {

    Login = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField(AppPreferences.getLastUserName());
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    p1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    p2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Login");
    addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
        formWindowOpened(evt);
      }
    });

    Login.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    Login.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0), 1, true));
    Login.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(517, 271));

    jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });

    jButton1.setText("LOGIN");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });
    jButton1.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
      public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
        jButton1KeyTyped(evt);
      }
    });

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("User name");

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText("Password");

    jButton2.setText("QUIT");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });
    jButton2.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
      public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
        jButton2KeyTyped(evt);
      }
    });

    p1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    p1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 51, 0));

    p2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    p2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
    p2.setText("              ");

    jLabel4.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/application/backoffice1/Ooredoo_Logo.png"))); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout LoginLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(Login);
    Login.setLayout(LoginLayout);
    LoginLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
         LoginLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(LoginLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 450, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(255, 255, 255)
            .addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, LoginLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(LoginLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(LoginLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 72, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 138, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(LoginLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 72, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 138, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addGap(337, 337, 337))
        .addGroup(LoginLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(206, 206, 206)
            .addGroup(LoginLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(LoginLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addGroup(LoginLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(p1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 236, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(p2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 153, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    LoginLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        LoginLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(LoginLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(LoginLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(LoginLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 99, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(LoginLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(LoginLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(p1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(p2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(LoginLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addComponent(jButton1))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(Login, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 450, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(Login, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 278, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
  }// </editor-fold>                        

  private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
    // TODO add your handling code here:
  }                                 

  /*Action du bouton QUIT activ avec la souris
    Ce bouton permet de fermer la fenêtre d'authentification
  */
  private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    System.exit(0);
  }                                        

  /*Action du bouton LOGIN activ avec la souris
    Ce bouton permet de valider l'identité de la personne selon les champs remplies
  */
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     try
     {
       AppPreferences.getLastUserName();
       
       // le meme déroulement qu'en action performed

       String Sql="Select  username,password   from   acteur    where username ='"+jTextField1.getText()+"'and password ='" +jPasswordField1.getText()+"'";
       con = getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/base_rapport","root","");
       stmt=con.createStatement();
       rs=stmt.executeQuery(Sql);
       if (rs.next()){
 
         AppPreferences.saveUserName(jTextField1.getText());
         p2.setText("welcome "+jTextField1.getText());
         nu=jTextField1.getText();
         p1.setText("");
         Principale s = new Principale();
         s.setVisible(true);
         this.dispose();
         
       }
       else
       {
          p1.setText("Invalid user name or password");
       }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"No data base connection");
    }
  }                                        

  /*Action du bouton LOGIN active avec la touche Enter
    Ce bouton permet de valider l'identité de la personne selon les champs remplis
  */

  private void jButton1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                  
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try
    {
      AppPreferences.getLastUserName();
       
          
    
      // le meme déroulement qu'en action performed

      String Sql="Select  username,password   from   acteur    where username ='"+jTextField1.getText()+"'and password ='" +jPasswordField1.getText()+"'";
      con = getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/base_rapport","root","");
      stmt=con.createStatement();
      rs=stmt.executeQuery(Sql);
      if (rs.next()){

        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"welcome "+jTextField1.getText());
        AppPreferences.saveUserName(jTextField1.getText());
        p2.setText("welcome "+jTextField1.getText());
        nu=jTextField1.getText();
        p1.setText("");
        Principale s = new Principale();
        s.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
      }
      else
      {
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"invalid username or password");
            
        p1.setText("Invalid user name or password");
            
      }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"No data base connection");
    }
  }                                 

  /*Action du bouton QUIT activ avec la touche Enter
    Ce bouton permet de fermer la fenêtre d'authentification
  */

  private void jButton2KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                  
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    System.exit(0); 
  }                                 

  private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
  }                                           

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
      for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
          javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
          break;
        }
      }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        new login().setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }
  // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
  private javax.swing.JPanel Login;
  private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
  private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
  private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
  private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
  private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
  private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
  private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
  private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
  private javax.swing.JLabel p1;
  private javax.swing.JLabel p2;
  // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Class names should start with an uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem, the deprecated method was replaced in the new version, and it's recommended to use the latest methods. 
it just a warning not an error. so you can still keep using it

[Is it wrong to use Deprecated methods or classes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941900/is-it-wrong-to-use-deprecated-methods-or-classes-in-java)

Comment: after building the project ,and when i tried to open the jar file a message appear could not find the main class : login

Comment: how your opening the jar?

Comment: using java(TM)Platform SE binary

Comment: I compiled your code and it works. can you past the eror

Comment: i build the code and i got a jar file for my application.When i tried to run it ,a message appears ( could not find the main class:login )

Comment: This is a classpath problem and it has nothing to do with the warning. Make sure your .class compiled file is on the JVM's classpath.