# How to pass data from an activity to a java class

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have reached the wall on the following. I am **trying to pass a variable from my main activity to a java class** that generates my database because **I want to use this variable in one of my queries of that database to get a result and then pass it to the Main activity**. Here's my piece of code:

```
//MainActivity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static RadioGroup selectedAvgStds;
     ...... //rest of the code/// 


    public void onClickListenerButton(){


    selectedAvgStds = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.controlAverageOfLiving);

    showResults.setOnClickListener(


        int avgStdLiving        = selectedAvgStds.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        selectedAvgStdsRb       = (RadioButton) findViewById(avgStdLiving);

        //variable that  I want to pass 
        String avgStdLivingText = (String) selectedAvgStdsRb.getText();

        switch (option) {
           case "one":
               Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DatabaseHelper.class);
               Intent.putExtra("values",avgStdLivingText);
               startActivity(intent);
           break;

          }
    );
}
```

Piece of code of my database

```
//DatabaseHelper
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public Cursor showResults(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    //the intent does NOT work
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    Cursor results = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TEMP_TABLE+"where value = " + selectedAvgStds , null);
    return results;
     }
}
```

The intent is not working despite the fact I have imported all the Intent libraries in the activity and the class. How can I achieve my goal? Why the Intents do not work here?

Any suggestion and idea will be enormously appreciated.

Comment: Your DatabaseHelper class isn't an Activity, so calling startActivity() on it clearly wont work :/ Where do you initialise your Database helper?

Comment: What about parametrizing your `showResults()` method?

Comment: Your logic is flawed, clearly using `startActivity(intent);` does not work because `DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper` not an `Activity`.  However I wouldn't go about changing that.  Why not just have an instance of `DatabaseHelper` in your Activity and amend your method take a variable parameter?

Comment: i dont know why people are down voting this question? I thought this is a learning forum.

Comment: from this question i learnt that we cannot use default interface methods in Android at the moment. I was trying to find a solution with that. This is not a bad question.

Comment: Thanks @hariszhr for your comment. I am not that android savvy and I was concerned that the startActivity(intent) was not going to work as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559053/android-getintent-is-deprecated . How can I achieve this parametrizing method() ?

Comment: @EdGeorge I initalize my database helper in my main activity on the method protected void onCreate().

Comment: I think it means that u should try using databasehelper as a normal class. Create an object of that class inside onclicklistenerbutton method. And change the showresult method to take avgstdlivingtext as a parameter. Then do all the processing inside showresult method, as u r doing already. Try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment, why do you not simply make `DatabaseHelper` an instance variable and parameterize your `showResults` method as following:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private DatabaseHelper myDatabaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //initialise your helper here
        myDatabaseHelper = ...
    }

    public void onClickListenerButton(){

        // All your other stuff here...

        // variable that  I want to pass
        String avgStdLivingText = selectedAvgStdsRb.getText().toString();
        myDatabaseHelper.showResults(avgStdLivingText);
    }

}
```

And then within the helper class you can simply do:

```
public Cursor showResults(String selectedAvgStds){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor results = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TEMP_TABLE+"where value = " + selectedAvgStds , null);
        return results;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not able to get data using intent is that `SQLiteOpenHelper` class might not have the method definition for `getIntent()`. I would prefer you **use Shared Preferences** to store the data and retrieve it inside you `SQLiteOpenHelper` class.

Comment: How can I achieve this with the Shared preferences?