# What does @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") do in Android?

Tags: android, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I don't know about it completely. I think that it allows the deprecated code to be compiled. I want to know if the code under this line will always be run or not and does it depend on the software like Eclipse, studio you are working on?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/SuppressWarnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2941912/5261092) out.
Using `suppresswarnings` just tells the compiler not to warn you. It's still valid to use deprecated code, but usually there's a better way you should use instead.

Answer (score 1):

The code will be compiled with or without it.  It tells your IDE not to even warn you about it.  Sometimes you have a good reason for using deprecated code.  Putting this on those functions/classes reduces the number of warnings reported, which makes it easier to find important warnings of real problems.

Answer (score 0):

Disables compiler warnings... In this case, deprecated code... Just for your information, for show clean code