# App crashes with sms listener

Tags: android, crash, report

I am developing an app which will react when a text message is received.
The code I have got crashes my app when a text message is received but due to having to install the app on my own device I am unable to get any crash reports to identify the problem at the time of the crash.

The code shown no errors before its built using android studios.

```
    public class ReceiveTextMessage extends BroadcastReceiver{

    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();           //---get the SMS message passed in---
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String msg_from;
            if (bundle != null){
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                try{
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                        msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                        String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
//                            Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone give me a clue as to why the crash may occur or anyway I could find a crash report.

I have edited my code in many different ways all giving the same result.

Comment: have registered the receiver in manifest? Have you given permissions? have you requested runtime permissions? Also, be sure intent not null.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my own running code :

```
    public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        static final String ACTION =
                "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)) {
                Bundle pudsBundle = intent.getExtras();
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) pudsBundle.get("pdus");
                SmsMessage messages = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
                String phoneNumber = messages.getOriginatingAddress();
                if (phoneNumber != null && phoneNumber.contains(Constants.OTP_NUMBER)) {
                    this.abortBroadcast();
                    Log.i("ABORTED", "DONE");
                    Intent localIntent = new Intent(Constants.OTP_BROADCASTING_PACKAGE);
                    String otp = messages.getMessageBody();
                    if (otp != null && !otp.equals("")) {
                        otp = otp.substring(otp.length() - 5, otp.length() - 1);
                        localIntent.putExtra("message", otp);
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(localIntent);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

**In Manifest**

    <receiver android:name="your_path.SmsReceiver">
                <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

Permission :

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: After editing some code to implement my own functionality this worked!! Much appreciated.

Comment: Be carefull though with using **deprecated** methods - [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2941912/4782930)