# setLightTouchEnabled(false); deprecated - alternative?

Tags: android, css, webview, onclick

I have an app with a webview. I want to make the onclick highlight transparent.

`setLightTouchEnabled(false);` is deprecated now. Are there any alternatives?

I tried adding the `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`;
in the css, without any luck.

A link to an image that illustrates the issue:

[Button onclick highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aRza.jpg)

Comment: Which device you are using ?.In some devices -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); does not work.Try -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;

Comment: I'm currently testing on a Sony Xperia tablet. I saw a comment about rgba not working on Samsung, and it's not on Sony either. Using transparent instead of rgba doesn't make a difference, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
Webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN|View.FOCUS_UP);


Webview.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(true);
```

or Option 2:

```
mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { 
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       switch (event.getAction()) { 
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
               if (!v.hasFocus()) { 
                   v.requestFocus(); 
               } 
               break; 
       } 
       return false; 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. However, I can't get any of the options to solve the issue. Option 1 is deprecated. Neither of them makes a difference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941900/is-it-wrong-to-use-deprecated-methods-or-classes-in-java ///   you can use deprecated methods if it works fine