# How to Create a string array in cocos2d-x 3.17v

Tags: c++, arrays, string, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

I am new to Cocos2d-x I am using 3.17v i am have some trouble i am not able to create a string in cocos2dx
i want to create a string array for storing sprite file names

`String* cars[5];`

I Tried this it is not working and an error is occur saying

type 'String' is deprecated

Comment: Use the standard [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead? And make an array of *strings*, not an array of *pointers* to strings.

Comment: Deprecated means it should not be used. Code and API's do evolve, and some caracteristics do get deprecated in favor of new ways to do the things. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941900/is-it-wrong-to-use-deprecated-methods-or-classes-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you start using standard types such as [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/), and not `cocos2d::String`. Also, for arrays, you can use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

`std::vector` allows you to add objects of a certain type including duplicates.

```
std::vector<std::string> stringVector;
stringVector.push_back("my string");
```

There are multiple ways to construct/initialise/use `std::string` and `std::vector` objects, but you can easily find information about this all over the internet or in the documentation links I've provided above.