# How could I parse the parameters of a function?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a small scripting programming language to test my skills.

I was wondering how I could split the parameters in a function.
So the syntax goes like this:

```
test "bla,bla,bla", "othertext"
```

How could I split those 2 parameters at the `,` in the middle without worrying the `,` chars in the string? Is there a regex to make things a little more easy?

Comment: I would do string iteration / substringing, and manage that yourself (state for being in quotes)

Comment: I think you'll find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366281/tokenizing-a-string-but-ignoring-delimiters-within-quotes

Comment: You'd be best off using an actual parser.

Comment: I mean the question is similiar to the one linked, but I need a ',' between parameters, and I do not know how I could do that.

Comment: String.split() is your friend

Answer (score -1):

```
    String str = "\"bla,bla,bla\", \"othertext\"";
    int p = str.lastIndexOf(',');
    String parameter1 =str.substring(0, p);
    String parameter2 =str.substring(p+1);
```