# How to get commandLine & arguments of Process in Java 9

Tags: java, windows, process, java-9

Java 9 provied pretty way to get information of the `Process`, but I still don't know how to get the `CommandLine` & `arguments` of the process:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe E:\\test.txt");
ProcessHandle.Info info = p.toHandle().info();
String[] arguments = info.arguments().orElse(new String[]{});
System.out.println("Arguments : " + arguments.length);
System.out.println("Command : " + info.command().orElse("")); 
System.out.println("CommandLine : " + info.commandLine().orElse(""));
```

Result:

```
Arguments : 0
Command : C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
CommandLine :
```

But I am expecting:

```
Arguments : 1
Command : C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
CommandLine : C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe E:\\test.txt
```

Comment: Just to debug further, could you try replacing your ProcessHandler `p.toHandle()` with `ProcessHandle.current()` and execute to see, if you get some values in the expected fields? Mostly of the interest to see if the process handler of your current Process is appropriate or not.

Comment: Not lucky, still same.

Answer (score 12):

Seems this was reported in [JDK-8176725](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8176725). Here is the comment describing the issue:

> The command line arguments are not available via a non-privileged API for other processes
>   and so the Optional is always empty. The API is explicit that the values are OS specific.
>   If in the future, the arguments are available by a Window APIs, the implementation can be updated.
>
> BTW, the info structure is filled by native code; the assignments to the fields do not appear in the Java code.

Comment: Yes, seem this worked on Linux, MacOS but not in Window now.

Comment: Not very sure about the resolution of that bug, but it seems like as marked that would be taken up as a *Future Project*.

Comment: What's the current status of this issue? It's "resolved", but it doesn't seem to be so.

Comment: There is also a newer, open [JDK-8263139](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8263139) that looks like a duplicate but is not evaluated.

Answer (score 5):

[JDK-8176725](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8176725) indicates that this feature is not implemented yet for Windows. Here is an easy but slow workaround:

```
  /**
   * Returns the full command-line of the process.
   * <p>
   * This is a workaround for
   * <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/46768046/14731">https://stackoverflow.com/a/46768046/14731</a>
   *
   * @param processHandle a process handle
   * @return the command-line of the process
   * @throws UncheckedIOException if an I/O error occurs
   */
  private Optional<String> getCommandLine(ProcessHandle processHandle) throws UncheckedIOException {
    if (!isWindows) {
      return processHandle.info().commandLine();
    }
    long desiredProcessid = processHandle.pid();
    try {
      Process process = new ProcessBuilder("wmic", "process", "where", "ProcessID=" + desiredProcessid, "get",
        "commandline", "/format:list").
        redirectErrorStream(true).
        start();
      try (InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)) {
        while (true) {
          String line = reader.readLine();
          if (line == null) {
            return Optional.empty();
          }
          if (!line.startsWith("CommandLine=")) {
            continue;
          }
          return Optional.of(line.substring("CommandLine=".length()));
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Excellent workaround. To turn that into an array of strings equivalent to `info.arguments()`, one has then to tokenize the string, paying attention to quoted strings, e.g. using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366281/tokenizing-a-string-but-ignoring-delimiters-within-quotes#3366634 ; and then drop the first element which is the command name.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `ProcessBuilder` instead of `Runtime#exec()`

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("notepad.exe", "E:\\test.txt").start();
```

Or another way to create a process :

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"notepad.exe", "E:\\test.txt"});
```

Comment: It's the same result. I tried it before changing to Runtime.getRuntime()

Comment: did you try the same command as I mentioned? Or `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe", new String[] {"E:\\test.txt"});`

Comment: yes, just did it and same result. Thinking this is bug of java 9