# Java/Kotlin: Tokenize a string ignoring the contents of nested quotes

Tags: java, string, kotlin, tokenize

I would like to split a character by spaces but keep the spaces inside the quotes (and the quotes themselves). The problem is, the quotes can be nested, and also I would need to do this for both single and double quotes. So, from the line `this "'"is a possible option"'" and ""so is this"" and '''this one too''' and even ""mismatched quotes"` I would like to get `[this, "'"is a possible option"'", and, ""so is this"", and, '''this one too''', and, even, ""mismatched quotes"]`.

This question has already been asked, but not the exact question that I'm asking. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366281/tokenizing-a-string-but-ignoring-delimiters-within-quotes) are several solutions: one uses a matcher (in this case `"""x"""` would be split into `[""", x"""]`, so this is not what I need) and Apache Commons (which works with `"""x"""` but not with `""x""`, since it takes the first two double quotes and leaves the last two with `x`). There are also suggestions of writing a function to do so manually, but this would be the last resort.

Comment: I think there's no solution other than to build a custom parser.  No regex will match arbitrary nesting like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with the following regex: `["']+[^"']+?["']+`. Using that pattern you retrieve the indices where you want to split like this:

```
val indices = Regex(pattern).findAll(this).map{ listOf(it.range.start, it.range.endInclusive) }.flatten().toMutableList()
```

The rest is building the list out of substrings. Here the complete function:

```
fun String.splitByPattern(pattern: String): List<String> {

    val indices = Regex(pattern).findAll(this).map{ listOf(it.range.start, it.range.endInclusive) }.flatten().toMutableList()

    var lastIndex = 0
    return indices.mapIndexed { i, ele ->

        val end = if(i % 2 == 0) ele else ele + 1 // magic

        substring(lastIndex, end).apply {
            lastIndex = end
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
val str = """
this "'"is a possible option"'" and ""so is this"" and '''this one too''' and even ""mismatched quotes"
""".trim()

println(str.splitByPattern("""["']+[^"']+?["']+"""))
```

Output:

> [this , "'"is a possible option"'",  and , ""so is this"",  and , '''this one too''',  and even , ""mismatched quotes"]

Try it out on [Kotlin's playground](https://pl.kotl.in/B1QjTNIN4)!

Comment: Thank you! This does work for fishing out the parts inside the quotes (with quotes included). However, two things:
1. I wanted to also tokenize everything outside the quotes. So, instead of `..., and even, ...` I wanted to get `..., and, even, ...`.
2. For a string like `text "text with spaces" and more text` I get `[text, 'text with spaces"]`, and the last part without the quotes doesn't make it to the final list.
However, those are the things that I could just do manually, so, once again, thank you!