# Reading a line from a text file and splitting its contents and sort them and place them in the file with the new sorting order

Tags: java, file, sorting

I am beginner to java. I have a text file. I need to read the line from a text file and splitting its contents and sort them and place the line in the file with the new sorting order.

Lets say my file has the below contents:

```
900000:Expected Policy# Nopolicy, but found 12345 for the report 'AHQKEHB6-R05'
700020:Expected Policy# Nopolicy, but found 12345 for the report 'AHQKEHB6- R05'
800005:Expected Policy# Nopolicy, but found 12345 for the report 'AHQKEHB6-R05'
900000:Expected Policy# Nopolicy, but found 12345 for the report 'BPTHSRS-R05'
600000:Expected Policy# Nopolicy, but found 12345 for the report 'AHQKEHB6-R05'
```

Here I need to sort the file in descending based on the first number (eg: 900000) and report.

So the result should be something like:

900000:Expected Policy# Nopolicy, but found 12345 for the report 'BPTHSRS-R05'
900000:Expected Policy# Nopolicy, but found 12345 for the report 'AHQKEHB6-R05'
800005:Expected Policy# Nopolicy, but found 12345 for the report 'AHQKEHB6-R05'
700020:Expected Policy# Nopolicy, but found 12345 for the report 'AHQKEHB6-R05'
600000:Expected Policy# Nopolicy, but found 12345 for the report 'AHQKEHB6-R05'

Please give me an example that helps me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Plain alphabetic sort will give you this, no need to overengineer with splitting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would approach it. It is a simple exercise in file IO and then using the `Collections.sort()` method. As [Marko Topolnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103872/marko-topolnik) mentioned in his comment, you don't need to split the text if you are sorting on the first few chars in the whole String anyways.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File myFile = new File("/path/to/file"); //WHEREVER YOUR FILE IS

    /* Read in file */
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));
        String line = "";

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.add(line);
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    // Sort now
    Collections.sort(output, Collections.reverseOrder()); //Reverse order because your example asked for descending

    /* Now write */
    FileWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter("/path/to/sorted_file"); //Wherever you want it

        int idx = 0;
        for(String string : output) {
            String append = string + (++idx < output.size() ? System.getProperty("line.separator") : "");
            writer.write(append);
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String[] fileToString(String path) {
    File file = new File(path);
    Vector<String> contents = new Vector<String>();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        if (file.exists() && file.canRead()) {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                contents.add(line);
            }
            br.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
    return contents.toArray(new String[contents.size()]);
}

public void stringToFile(String path, String[] lines) {
    File file = new File(path);
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file)));
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            bw.write(lines[i] + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        if (bw != null) {
            try {
                bw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}

public void example() {
    String[] lines = fileToString("myFile.txt");
    Arrays.sort(lines, Collections.reverseOrder());
    stringToFile("myOtherFile.txt", lines);
}
```

Comment: This is right, but I just wanted to point out that the use of `Vector` in Java is not advised. Please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 If Vector were such a bad thing it would be deprecated but it's not http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/deprecated-list.html

Comment: It is what is known as a "legacy class." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086307/what-are-the-legacy-classes-in-java