# Is a .gradle file in buildSrc folder a plugin for projects?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am learning gradle from the gradle official website:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html

Here, in one of the example, it has a file in buildSrc folder-

**buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/myproject.java-conventions.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    id("java")
}

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13")
}
```

The structure of the project is:

```
.
├── buildSrc
│   ...
├── api
│   ├── src
│   │   └──...
│   └── build.gradle.kts
├── services
│   └── person-service
│       ├── src
│       │   └──...
│       └── build.gradle.kts
├── shared
│   ├── src
│   │   └──...
│   └── build.gradle.kts
└── settings.gradle.kts
```

The module build scripts **api/build.gradle.kts** and **shared/build.gradle.kts** are using the plugin **'myproject.java-conventions'** as:

```
plugins {
    id("myproject.java-conventions")
}
```

I referred the below about how to create custom plugins.

[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gradle/gradle_plugins.htm#:~:text=Plugin%20is%20nothing%20but%20set,are%20handled%20by%20plugins.&text=Extend%20the%20basic%20Gradle%20model,elements%20that%20can%20be%20configured](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gradle/gradle_plugins.htm#:%7E:text=Plugin%20is%20nothing%20but%20set,are%20handled%20by%20plugins.&text=Extend%20the%20basic%20Gradle%20model,elements%20that%20can%20be%20configured)).

I am confused about how just having a .gradle or .gradle.kts file in buildSrc is a plugin that projects are able to use. And, if so, why are they not using that as:

apply plugin: myproject.java-conventions

What is the difference then in apply plugin `apply plugin: myproject.java-conventions` and

```
plugins {
    id("myproject.java-conventions")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `myproject.java-conventions.gradle.kts` file is a gradle plugin. Specifically, it is a [precompiled script plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins). All sub-modules are able to use this plugin because by [packaging a plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:packaging_a_plugin) in the `buildSrc` project,

> Gradle will take care of... making it available on the classpath of the build script. The plugin is visible to every build script used by the build.

The `plugins` block is simply a newer method of applying plugins. See: [What's the difference in applying gradle plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352816/)