# Understanding all the ways to apply a plugin in Gradle

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to understand all the ways you can apply a plugin in Gradle, Kotlin DSL.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352816/what-the-difference-in-applying-gradle-plugin) question answers part of my question, but not all of it (I'm guessing methods have been added in the six years that have passed since them).

I've seen this exact scenario in one of my `build.gradle.kts` files.

```kotlin
plugins{
   `kotlin-dsl`
   kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.10"
   id("com.foo.bar.someplugin") version 1.2.3
}

apply("foo2.bar2.anotherplugin")
```

Wow, that's four different ways to apply a plugin and I don't really understand the relationship between them at all.  From the other answer, I get that `apply(...)` is the legacy way and will eventually be deprecated, but what about the other three?

Furthermore, I'm confused by why the `` `kotlin-dsl` `` doesn't even need a version.  What is this voodoo magic?

And finally, for the sake of consistency, I would like to standardize the plugins block (let's ignore the `apply(...)` since it's legacy functionality) so that everything uses `id(...)`.  How do I convert the other two?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is actually mostly only 2 ways, which you already identified: the buildscript dependency + `apply`, or the `plugins` block. What's in your plugins block here is actually just helpers:

- `id("some.plugin.id") version "version"` is the basic way of registering a plugin with an ID and a version
- `kotlin()` is really just a helper function provided by the Kotlin DSL that calls `id()` behind the scenes with a `org.jetbrains.kotlin.` prefix before whatever string you passed. So `kotlin("jvm")` is just a shorthand for `id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")`
- `kotlin-dsl` is also a helper function that is a shortcut for the Kotlin DSL Gradle plugin. I believe the string ID is `org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl`.

In the legacy way of applying plugins, you had to declare the dependency on the plugin in the `buildscript` block so the classes of the plugin are added to the classpath for the compilation/execution of the Gradle script itself. As a second step, calling `apply` would actually apply the plugin to the current project.

With the `plugins` block, both happen at the same time, so it's more convenient to use. You can also add `apply false` after the plugin declaration so that it's just added to the classpath without also applying it to the project:

```
plugins {
    id("com.foo.bar.someplugin") version 1.2.3 apply false
}
```

This is useful if you want to declare all plugins and their versions in the root project, and then just apply the relevant ones in subprojects by using the `plugins` block without versions:

```
plugins {
    id("com.foo.bar.someplugin")
}
```

> Furthermore, I'm confused by why the `kotlin-dsl` doesn't even need a version. What is this voodoo magic?

As you can see from the above explanation, any plugin that's already on the classpath doesn't need a version. This applies to plugins that are already declared in a parent project, or in the `settings.gradle(.kts)`'s `plugins`, and to built-in Gradle plugins.

The Kotlin DSL plugin is a built-in Gradle plugin, so it uses a version that's dependent on the version of Gradle you are using. It is similar to the `java` or `application` plugins.

It's also explicitly advised to avoid specifying the version for it [in the doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:kotlin-dsl_plugin):

> Avoid specifying a version for the kotlin-dsl plugin.
> Each Gradle release is meant to be used with a specific version of the kotlin-dsl plugin and compatibility between arbitrary Gradle releases and kotlin-dsl plugin versions is not guaranteed. Using an unexpected version of the kotlin-dsl plugin in a build will emit a warning and can cause hard to diagnose problems.

Now as for your other question:

> I would like to standardize the plugins block (let's ignore the apply(...) since it's legacy functionality) so that everything uses id(...). How do I convert the other two?

The way they are written here is quite idiomatic, so this should be considered the "standard". This is actually how it's advised to be used in the doc. Using `kotlin-dsl` is a nice way to distinguish built-in Gradle plugins from third party plugins. Also, it is a type-safe way to declare the plugin, it's understood by the IDE and you can search for references etc. Strings are just inferior in this respect.

If you really really wanted to apply it with the string-based syntax, you could probably use `id("org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl")`, but I've never seen a project do that so far.

The `kotlin()` helper could be more debatable, and a matter of personal taste, but IMO the less arbitrary strings, the better.

Comment: I'm bothered by the fact that the `kotlin-dsl` version is determined the gradle version, not the gradle configuration.  Everything else is declared _as part of the configuration_, so you know what you're getting.  Whereas `kotlin-dsl` could inadvertently have a version change by upgrading Gradle.  Do you think that's not a problem?  Why?

Comment: I was a bit to late to add the reference to the doc in my answer apparently :) I don't think it's a problem because this plugin is meant to affect the way the Gradle build works, it's meant mostly for the `buildSrc`'s gradle build script, which compiles code that will be used by Gradle itself, so it makes sense it is aligned with Gradle's version. Also, it's better for compatibility because a fixed version wouldn't be guaranteed to produce code that works with later Gradle versions