# Android Gradle - Error while adding Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

I was following the Firebase doc which told me to put this line

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

It told to put this below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

but I don't have any line like this, all I have is this:-

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}
```

Where should I put the above line? (Also see that, I am new to programming so please explain whatever solution you give :)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it like this:

```
 plugins {
      id 'com.android.application'
      id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
 }
```

Actually, both ways roughly do the same thing.

Comment: You can refer to this for further explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352816/what-the-difference-in-applying-gradle-plugin