# How to find gradle plugin id for given gradle library?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am currently updating my project and as one of the steps I am changing gradle files to use the `plugins { id 'xxx' }` way instead of the legacy `apply plugin 'xxx'` approach. I was able to migrate most of the imports to the new format, however I cannot add some plugins, as I am unable to find their gradle plugin ids.

For example, here are my old gradle files:

settings.gradle file

```
include ':app'
```

project's build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        (...)
    }
    dependencies {
        (...)
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.0'
        classpath 'com.google.android.gms:oss-licenses-plugin:0.10.5'
    }
}
(...)
```

module's build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'com.google.android.gms.oss-licenses-plugin'
(...)
```

And here are partially modified new gradle files:

settings.gradle file

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "xxxx"
include ':app'
```

project's build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' version '2.9.2' apply false
    // DOESN'T WORK:
    id 'com.google.android.gms.oss-licenses-plugin' version '0.10.5' apply false
}
(...)
```

module's build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    // NEED TO SET SAME ID AS IN PROJECT'S GRADLE FILE PROBABLY:
    id 'com.google.android.gms.oss-licenses-plugin'
    (...)
}
```

Problem lays in how to get gradle plugin id for given plugin?
Many plugin installation instructions use the old `apply plugin` approach and I don't want to mix both of them.

For example in case of Crashlytics with classpath of `com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle`, the id is `com.google.firebase.crashlytics` - how was I supposed to know that? I found this in one of the answers on Stackoverflow, but without information about how someone knew that.

Currently I am trying to add the oss-licenses-plugin and I am completly clueless as about how to find its gradle plugin id...
Any suggestions?

Or maybe it is not guaranteed that every plugin added with use of `classpath` can be translated to the new `plugins { }` way? In this case, how can I tell it is this situation?

Comment: I have researched a little bit and in the case of crashlytics, the path is the same as the directory structure if you download the jar file and you extract it. Unfortunately, I have tried the same approach with `com.google.android.gms.oss-licenses-plugin`which should be converted to `com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.plugin` according to the directory structure and it is not working.

Comment: Have ```com.google.android.gms.oss-licenses-plugin```following ```com.android.application```prior to ```com.google.firebase.crashlytics``` - see whether that helps - otherwise I am just as stumped

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a certain pattern that plugin publishers need to follow in order for Gradle to find the plugin implementation. A `properties` file needs to be included in the JAR's `META-INF/gradle-plugins` directory. And the name of this file needs to be formatted in the following way:

```
<plugin-id>.properties
```

And inside this file, the plugin implementation is defined:

```
implementation-class=<com.example.SomePluginImpl>
```

So, to answer your question, you'll need to get a hold of the JAR & look at its contents to figure out the id: `META-INF/gradle-plugins/<plugin-id>.properties`.

For `com.google.android.gms.oss-licenses-plugin`, I checked here: [Link](https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/tree/master/oss-licenses-plugin/src/main/resources/META-INF/gradle-plugins). Alternatively, you can grab the JAR from maven, extract its contents & check the **properties** file: [Link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/oss-licenses-plugin/0.10.5).

The other issue with your code is that for external plugin resolution, you need to define a `resolutionStrategy` under `pluginManagement`:

```
pluginManagement {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.id == 'com.google.android.gms.oss-licenses-plugin') {
                useModule "com.google.android.gms:oss-licenses-plugin:${requested.version}"
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to use `id 'com.google.android.gms.oss-licenses-plugin' version '0.10.5' apply false` in your project-level **build.gradle**.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer! Well, is it just me or is it way too complicated in the current form? I hope it is just some transitional period and with time all plugins will be migrated to gradle repo, so there's no need for such workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

according to [gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html), you can find the plugin registered in [here](https://plugins.gradle.org/)

not all gradle plugin available, because the dev need to publish their plugin to gradle first, here how to publish the plugin https://plugins.gradle.org/docs/publish-plugin

edit :
I tried to find oss-licenses-plugin, no luck with that. So you should use the old method to apply the plugin.

other info : [What the difference in applying gradle plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352816/what-the-difference-in-applying-gradle-plugin)