# How to use Open Source Notices library with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-theme

I'm using the official Google library for open source notices: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/opensource

But when I try to start the activity

```
Button(
    onClick = {
        context.startActivity(Intent(context, OssLicensesMenuActivity::class.java))
    }
) {
    Text(text = "Open Source Licenses")
}
```

I get error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.OssLicensesMenuActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Is there some way to use the app's default Compose theme to launch an activity?

I know that I can specify the `AppCompat` theme in the manifest and the crash will stop but I'd like to somehow use my Compose theme. Is it even possible?

Comment: accept the answer below, it's correct, verified

Comment: It is partially correct (I'm asking how to use it with the Compose theme, not AppCompat theme), but I'll accept it as an answer. 

If it is useful to someone, perhaps the best solution would be to use a third-party library compatible with Compose, for example this https://github.com/mikepenz/AboutLibraries
or this https://github.com/usefulness/licensee-for-android (used in the official ChatGPT app).

Unfortunately the official OSS Licenses Plugin by Google is updated quite slowly (last release was in December 2022, version 0.10.6). Perhaps it was abandoned.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using AppCompat theme separately just for OSS activity, you can keep MaterialTheme for your activities. Also AppCompat is the only way in other cases like per-app language preferences which works only with AppCompat theme - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74413010/7767664 But it's fine and it doesn't effect anything because we set it only at style xml, but inside `setContent` we use Material Theme for Compose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app uses a nice new theme rather than the old AppCompat ones this library expects. You can set a different theme just for the Activities in this library though. eg:

```xml
    <!-- Google OSS Licenses library is a bit old, doesn't work with our theme. Set a compatible theme for its Activities -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.OssLicensesMenuActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.OssLicensesActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />
```

Also, heads up for the next issues you'll likely encounter:

1. This library only generates a list for release builds, so you can only verify it worked on those (a pain for QA if they use debug builds).
2. The list it generates seems to have lots of duplication and yet also things missing.

Personally each time I try to use this library I find it to be a bit lacking for any real practical use and end up going to something else. It seems to be a bit too optimistic that all libraries will do the right thing, and not well maintained or supported, ie. no docs to make it work with Compose, or [with modern gradle plugins DSL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74411243/55488).

I used to use the [cookpad library](https://github.com/cookpad/LicenseToolsPlugin) for this but they have said it's now deprecated in favour of this, even though IMO theirs was much more thorough, flexible + practical, ie. generate list with all libraries, let you fill in what's missing, then generate final output from that. More work, but you were sure you'd covered all your libraries. There's also [this library](https://github.com/jaredsburrows/gradle-license-plugin), haven't tried it yet but I think that's next on my list to look at.

Comment: I tried adding those activity tags, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Thanks! I used `<style name="Theme.App.Notices" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar" />` @realh it works.