# How to use android-reporting plugin with Kotlin DSL and Version Catalog?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Following this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line#multi-module-reports-instrumented-tests) to get multi-module test reports for instrumented tests in a single HTML page, how to use it when using Kotlin DSL with Version Catalog?

So far none of these approach work

Version Catalog

```
[plugins]
reporting = { id = "android-reporting", version.ref = "android-gradle-plugin" }
```

Using alias

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.android.kotlin) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.reporting) apply false
}
```

Using id

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.android.kotlin) apply false
    id(libs.plugins.reporting.get().pluginId) apply false
}
```

Does this plugin still maintain? I saw only one version in Maven and it is in alpha.

It is also not working with this structure, the test report still not merged in to single location.

```
:app
  libs
    :module1
    :module2
```